# Issue with exporting anki card rating and time on csv

Tags: python, csv, anki

I have created an add-on that outputs a csv file with the ratings of anki cards and the time they were rated.
In the anki-review_results folder, I stored an empty ****init**.py**, **anki_rating_time_record.py**, and a file named **manifest.json**, and after compressing it, I converted the extension to .ankiaddon.
However, I got the following error
An error occurred during the installation of anki-review-results.ankiaddon: Invalid add-on manifest.
Please report this to the add-on author in question.

Anki_rating_time_record.py is as follows

```
import anki_python_api
import csv
import datetime

# reset anki api
Anki = anki_python_api.

review_results = []

def review_did_answer_card(result, card, ease):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    review_results.append((result, card, ease, now))
    
# register Anki API
anki.add_review_did_answer_card_callback(review_did_answer_card)

# start anki
anki.run()

# save the results on csv format
with open("review_results.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writer(["timestamp", "result", "card", "ease"])
    for all_results in review_results:
        writer.writer([all_result[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),all_result[1],
                         all_result[2],all_result[3]])
```

The manifest.json is as follows.

```
{
    "id" : "anki-review-results",
    "version": "0.1",
    "name": "Anki Review Results",
    "description": "Save the results of your Anki reviews in a CSV file",
    "author": "Shohei",
    "addonType":["background"],
    "minimumAnkiVersion": "2.1.0"
    "files":["Anki_rating_time_record.py","_init_.py"]
}
```

The version of anki in use is 2.1.58.
What can I do to make it function properly? Please let me know.

Comment: I see you using writer.writer() where I expect to see writer.writerow(). Is that a typo, do you mean to use writerow()?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo.
However, when the file was run, there were no typos, and I suspect the problem is in the way manifest.json is written.
If you come up with any solutions, please let me know.

Comment: Hmm, I’m not sure what Anki is… I only looked at this question because it was tagged CSV, and you’re showing code for writing CSV (which I understand), but I don’t see how a JSON file fits in… I suppose that’s the Anki part. Good luck 